# Network has no ping and can't resolve hosts

Tags: centos, networking, dns

This is the config on `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`:

```
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=c7sdfsdf-dfgdgdfgdgd-dg
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=x.x.x.x
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=x.x.x.y
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=4.2.2.4
ARPCHECK=no
HWADDR=00:0C:29:9D:D1:CC
```

and also `resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 4.2.2.4
```

Now I don't have ping and cant wget google.com:

```
From x.x.x.y icmp_seq=1 Destination Net Unreachable
```

AND

```
# curl http://google.com
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'google.com'
```

## Update

```
# nslookup google.com
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

# dig ns.google.com @8.8.8.8

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6_6.1 <<>> ns.google.com @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Comment: Can you ping your gateway??  Are your Gateway and your static IP address in the same subnet and Address Class?

Comment: Yes I can ping the gateway...Yes they are.. IP:a.a.a.a Gateway:a.a.a.b

Comment: I'm assuming here since you are being rather vague, that your Gateway is a.a.a.1, which means your IP address should be a.a.a.x where x is between 2 and 254.  Am I still correct?

Comment: Yes. You are correct////

Comment: @eyoung100 please see the update

Comment: How were you given a.a.a.x?  Did you just pull a.a.a.x out of the air?

Comment: No I got it from isp... Are there miscofiguration on my centOS, you think?

Comment: Can you see your default route in `ip -d route`?

Comment: Is the address Dynamically Assigned by the ISP, or are you paying for a Static IP

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned already in the comments, you should check your **default route**.  This can be achieved with e.g. `$ ip r`.  You should see something like this:

```
$ ip r
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth1 
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.143 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link  metric 1001
```

Note: The *default* value could also be indicated with an address of `0.0.0.0`.

Should you find that you're missing the default route from your system, do

```
$ ip r add default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth1
```

Obviously, you should replace your own values for the IP address of your Router/Gateway and the *dev* argument (eth1) as the name of your desired interface name.

Answer (score 0):

Should probably be a comment, but is just too long. This is meant to be the start of a network troubleshooting check list, please add/correct as needed.

This are symptoms of a hosed setup. Please check the manual pages of the commands mentioned.

Check the cables are firmly set, see if the idiot lights (if available) blink on both ends.

What does `ip link list` say? Any `NO CARRIER` means a card that isn't connected. If your card isn't listed, it is probably broken.

What does `ip route list` say?

Ask `nmcli` what it thinks about the setup (it has lots of functions, check it's manual). Check at least `nmcli g`, `nmcli d`, and `nmcli c`

`nm-online` should try to set up networking, if it doesn't it might give some more information.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, My problem was typo in gateway ip insted of "**192.168.0.1**" it was 
"**19.168.0.1**" after correcting it got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

since the DNS is not accessible the problem cannot be grounded,

Try pinging dns

`ping 8.8.8.8`

If it is pinging then the issue is that either you need configure some proxy or gateway or need to avail some additional settings to access dns from your service provider
With above stated issue it actually should not work, So ping your gateway

`ping x.x.x.y` (your gateway ip address)

in case, if it is pinging then you need to do traceroute/tracepath to gateway

in linux
`traceroute x.x.x.y` (your gateway ip)

in windows
`tracert x.x.x.y`

Normally the issue can be tracked here if your gateway is not getting pinged(if it keeps on showing asterisk signs then your gateway is not accessible)
If it is showing that it is reaching the gateway in somehops

try
`traceroute 8.8.8.8`

Here you'll know the ip which is actually troubling you. Based on that we can conclude, what you need to configure additionally